# Can I draw a border around a sprite image (ExtJS)?

Tags: extjs, components, border, draw, sprite

I have a sprite image that i have added to a drawComponent instance.
On click of that sprite, I want to draw a border around that image.

```
var myImg=surface.add({
            type: "image",
            src: <some path>,
            x:50,
            y:50,
            height:100,
            width:100,            
            draggable:true
        });
```

I also tried using the addCls() method  to include this CSS

```
.imgCls
{
border-style:solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 5px;
 }
```

But I don't find it drawing any border aroound the image.

Please help. Thanks !

**Update:**

Used setStyle() method and redrew the image.

```
myImg.setStyle('border','5px solid #000000');
myImg.redraw();
```

No border is drawn and no errors reported either.

Comment: which version of extjs are you using?

Comment: have you tried using the border config on the `image`? did that work?

Comment: I'm not sure if there a border config for `image` for Sprites. Please check http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite. Are you talking about `Ext.Img` class ?

Comment: my mistake. for `Ext.draw.Sprite`, have you tried using `addCls()`?

Comment: Yes. The script doesn't report any error. But I don't find any effect on the image once rendered.  See the CSS above ? I tried including that using `addCls()`. In vain.

Comment: Any help/suggestions for this problem ?